# Does having a lot of using/import statements indicate bad design or code smell?

Tags: programming-practices

Typically, I see a few using statement at the top of class file.  Example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

But in a project I am working on, on several occasions I see 20 or more usings/imports in one class file.  Is this bad design?  It seems to be that classes designed to do one thing should only rely on a few components.

Comment: Visual Studio has an option to remove unused `using` statements.  You might want to see how many of those 20 are in actual use.

Comment: @Dan -They are all in use as I have used ReSharper to weed out the unused ones.

Comment: Have you tried with adding an IoC, converting to constructor injection, and/or convert some integration points into inline lambdas to see if it will reduce the number of `using` statements without having to increase the number of classes? Keep in mind that increasing number of classes or source files will increase source code management overhead.

Comment: IoC just hides the problem.

Comment: Some of those things are almost just part of the language and the programming style it encourages, like Collections.Generic and LINQ, so I wouldn't necessarily worry about those.  I'd probably focus my attention on the others.  Most classes probably shouldn't need to do IO directly, so, perhaps if that's found everywhere there's some conflating of responsibilities or poor layering, but it does depend on the application.

Comment: If you've weeded out those that aren't in use it indicates nothing more nefarious than complexity. Whether this complexity is required is something only you can answer with eyes on the actual code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can indicate a bad design, yes. It might be that the class you're looking at is doing too many things, but it also might mean that the namespaces you're importing are really more coupled than the namespace separation implies. That may be because of over-engineer or over-abstraction, but it also might just be a design that doesn't align well with use.

That said, it's a smell - sometimes it leads you to something bad, and sometimes it's just a false alarm.

Comment: I think the true "code smell" would be if the imported namespaces are all, or mostly, wildly different in purpose. To be honest, I've rarely had more than 6 to 8 `using`'s in a single C# file.

Comment: I'd like to give you a second +1 if I could, just for using the term "code smell" correctly!

Comment: !@Greg - I agree, usually the "usings" are related.  I think in this case it's a case over abstraction because about 15-20 of the "usings" come from application namespaces and the rest from .net framework.

Answer (score 2):

A class should be no bigger and no smaller than what is needed to provide an intended function.

In one application, I have an encryption class that has one job: encrypt data. Between the core functionality, logging, and exception handling, the environment requires 11 distinct namespace imports to do this one job.

It's hard for me to tell myself 'minimize imports'. Or to judge my class' success solely by counting the number of imported namespaces. I can't justifiably use this, in isolation, as an indication of a class' success. To me, 'imports' are the means to the class' end. If the class' job is well-defined, everything else within the supporting system, including imports, will take care of itself.